# Cambiar check de radio cuando se de click en un elemento asociado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito que cuando yo le de click a la tag `a` el radio se chequee. Hice una función para hacerlo y lo hace bien, el problema es que si quiero chequear otra que ya había chequeado ya no lo hace. Necesito las tags en ese orden y no puedo hacerlo.

Bienvenidas todas las sugerencias

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('click','a',function(e){
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked','checked');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" checked>Opcion 1</a>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" >Opcion 2</a>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" >Opcion 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Entonces lo que te falta es que desmarque el botón o que es lo que te falta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar `.attr()` para asignar el checked deberías usar [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> El método `.prop()` proporciona una forma de recuperar explícitamente valores de una propiedad, mientras `.attr()` recupera atributos.

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('click','a',function(e){
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked','checked');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" checked>Opcion 1</a>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" >Opcion 2</a>
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" >Opcion 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona! Gracias

Comment: Camilo, solo una cosa, dejó de funcionar el evento nativo del radio, que me recomiendas.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob eso es por que tienes el <input> dentro de tu <a> y en la función estas ejecutando un preventDefault() lo cual anula el comportamiento por defecto del elemento, es por eso que no funciona clicando en el input directamente

Comment: Resuelto, gracias @CamiloVasquez

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que cada que agregas el atributo `checked` al radio hijo que seleccionas este queda ahí aun cuando seleccionas otro elemento, por ejemplo cuando haces clic sobre cada uno el html queda de esta manera:

```html
<div>
    <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" checked="checked">Opcion 1</a>
    <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked">Opcion 2</a>
    <a href="#"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" checked="checked">Opcion 3</a>
</div>
```

por tanto al volver a hacer clic ya no funciona.
Mencionaria el metodo removeAttr como una solución pero el uso de attr y similares esta deprecado y lo mejor en estos casos es utilizar el metodo `prop('checked', 'cheked')` para agregar el atributo.

Otra manera mas sencilla de lograr lo que deseas es utilizado la etiqueta `label` y enlazándola a tu checkbox mediante el atributo `for="id"`

```html
<a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="radio-1">Opcion 1</label></a>
<a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" value="1"><label for="radio-2">Opcion 2</label></a>
<a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" value="2"><label for="radio-3">Opcion 3</label></a>
```

De esta manera no necesitas utilizar jquery y enlazar eventos.